# Creating a multiline textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "textarea");
    y.setAttribute("type", "file");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help us with the code for creating a visible multi-line text area in the same language as the code.

Comment: You haven't described the problem you're having. Also, what's jQuery got to do with this?

Comment: <input type="textarea"> doesn't exist. You probably mean <textarea> ?

Answer (score 2):

`textarea` isn't a type of `<input>`. `<textarea>` is its own tag:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.createElement("textarea");
  var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
  y.setAttribute("type", "file");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  document.body.appendChild(y);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.createElement("INPUT")` to `.createElement("TEXTAREA")`

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "file");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea elements aren't inputs, they're their own thing.

```html
<body>

<p>Click the button to create a File Upload Button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
    var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
    y.setAttribute("type", "file");
    document.body.appendChild(x);
    document.body.appendChild(y);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```